# NameError: name 'd' is not defined in param_check

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the following sets of coding challenges, but generate one error after another.

```py
def checkingIfIn(a, direction=True, 
                 d={'apple': 2, 'pear': 1, 'fruit': 19, 'orange': 5, 
                    'banana': 3, 'grapes': 2, 'watermelon': 7}):

    if direction == True:
        if a in d is True:
            return d[a]
        else:
            return False
    else:
        if a not in d:
            return True
        else:
            return d[a]
```

- Call the function so that it returns False and assign that function
  call to the variable c_false
- Call the fucntion so that it returns True and assign it to the
  variable c_true
- Call the function so that the value of fruit is assigned to the
  variable fruit_ans
- Call the function using the first and third parameter so that the
  value 8 is assigned to the variable param_check

```py
c_false = checkingIfIn('wwww',direction=True)       
c_true = checkingIfIn('bbbbb',direction=False)
fruit_ans = checkingIfIn('fruit',True)
param_check = checkingIfIn('apple',True,(d(['pear']['watermelon'])))

print(c_false)
print(c_true)
print(fruit_ans)
print(param_check)
```

Comment: Can you format your code with triple backquotes so we can read it easily, and show us the output of your console with the errors ?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing stuff up.

1)
First off, the method is not d.keys[a], it's d.keys()

```
if a in d.keys()
```

2)
In your else case you're also being incoherent because you're writing

```
if a not in d
```

when it should be

```
if a not in d.keys()
```

3)
for fruit_ans you're assigning d='apple'. Now d is a string, not a dictionary, so of course it won't work (string don't have keys)

You're actually doing something useless by even passing something to d. You should be passing just

```
checkingIfIn('apple',True)
```

And this will check if key apple is contained in your dictionary d.
Otherwise you need to pass a proper dictionary to d

```
checkingIfIn('apple',True, d={'this':1,'is':2,'aProper':3,'dictionary':4})
```

4)
You're assigning an integer to d for the param_check. Which is the same error you made in point 3, passing something that is not a dictionary to d

5) Your comments for each function call are quite hard to figure out. It's not clear what you even want to achieve with this method but it's clearly in dire need to be reworked

EDIT:

This is what you get by using your method properly

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Call the function so that it returns False and 
    #assign that function call to the variable c_false
    c_false = checkingIfIn('apple',direction=False)        

    #Call the fucntion so that it returns True and assign it to the
    #variable c_true
    c_true = checkingIfIn('apple',direction=True)

    #Call the function so that the value of fruit is assigned to the
    #variable fruit_ans
    fruit_ans = checkingIfIn('apple',True,d={'apple':1})

    #Call the function using the first and third parameter so that the
    #value 8 is assigned to the variable param_check
    param_check = checkingIfIn('apple',direction=True)            

    print(c_false)
    print(c_true)
    print(fruit_ans)
    print(param_check)
```

And the output is as follows

```
2
apple
apple
apple
```

Which clearly isn't what you're trying to get, but again, your code and your comments aren't exactly easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkingIfIn(a, direction = True, d= {'apple': 2, 'pear': 1, 'fruit': 19,     'orange': 5, 'banana': 3, 'grapes': 2, 'watermelon': 7}):
    if direction == True:
        if a in d:
            return d[a]
        else:
            return False
    else:
        if a not in d:
            return True
        else:
            return d[a]
```

- Call the function so that it returns False and assign that function call to the variable c_false
- Call the fucntion so that it returns True and assign it to the variable c_true
- Call the function so that the value of fruit is assigned to the variable fruit_ans
- Call the function using the first and third parameter so that the value 8 is assigned to the variable param_check

---

```
c_false = checkingIfIn('wwww',direction=True)       

c_true = checkingIfIn('bbbbb',direction=False)

fruit_ans = checkingIfIn('fruit',True)

param_check = checkingIfIn('apple',True,('pear')+('watermelon'))

print(c_false)
print(c_true)
print(fruit_ans)
print(param_check)
```